# Javascript - getElementsByTagName - skip first element | Sharepoint 2019 - Table of content

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, getelementsbytagname, tableofcontents

i found a script that creates a table of content for sharepoint sites. It works fine, but at our sharepoint sites the first headline (H1) is the page title. So i have to skip the first Headline (Page title).

Does anybody know which part i have to edit to fit the skript for my needs? =)

```
    <!-- 
The TOC Container.
The most important thing to note is the ID.
The ID is used by the CSS and the JavaScript code.
-->
<ul id="sp-toc"></ul>

<style type="text/css">
    #sp-toc {
        padding: 10px;
        /* Add a padding between the border and the TOC content */
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        /* Add a background color of the TOC */
        min-width: 200px;
        /* Add only a minimal width like that, the TOC can be extensible */
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        /* Add a border arround the TOC */
        list-style: none;
        /* Remove default style list */
    }

    #sp-toc li {
        /* If you need to add custom style on all <li> */
    }

    #sp-toc li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        /* Remove default link underline */
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h1 {
        /* currently, the first level supported by the script */
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h2 {
        /* Add a indentation greatter than the previous one */
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h3 {
        /* Add a indentation greatter than the previous one */
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h4 {
        /* Add a indentation greatter than the previous one */
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h5 {
        /* Add a indentation greatter than the previous one */
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h6 {
        /* Add a indentation greatter than the previous one */
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * The main function to build TOC
     */
    function buildToc() {
        /* Init title level counters */
        var countH1 = countH2 = countH3 = countH4 = countH5 = countH6 = 0;

        /**
         * DOMElement : the TOC container retrieved by ID
         */
        var toc = document.getElementById("sp-toc");

        /**
         * Insert into TOC container the chapters
         */
        toc.innerHTML = nodesToc();

        /**
         * TOC Builder
         */
        function nodesToc() {
            /* Get all HTML tags from the current page */
            var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            var tagList = "H1;H2;H3;H4;H5;H6;";
            var str = "";
            /* Loop on each HTML tag */
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                /* If tag is a title tag */
                if (tagList.indexOf(obj[i].tagName + ";") >= 0) {
                    /* Get the number of the multilevel list in accordance with the current title */
                    var lvl = getNumberLevel(obj[i].tagName);
                    /* HTML template */
                    str += "<li class='" + getClassLvl(obj[i].tagName) + "'><a href='#title-" + i + "'>" + lvl + " " + obj[i].innerHTML + "</a></li>";
                    obj[i].id = "title-" + i;
                }
            }
            return str;
        }

        /**
         * Get CSS class in accordance with the title level
         */
        function getClassLvl(_tagName) {
            return "class-toc-h" + _tagName.replace(/h/ig, '');
        }

        /**
         * Multilevel list generator
         */
        function getNumberLevel(_tagName) {
            if (_tagName === "H1") {
                countH2 = countH3 = countH4 = countH5 = countH6 = 0;
                return ++countH1;
            } else if (_tagName === "H2") {
                countH3 = countH4 = countH5 = countH6 = 0;
                return countH1 + "." + ++countH2;
            } else if (_tagName === "H3") {
                countH4 = countH5 = countH6 = 0; /* Reset next level number */
                return countH1 + "." + countH2 + "." + ++countH3;
            } else if (_tagName === "H4") {
                countH5 = countH6 = 0; /* Reset next level number */
                return countH1 + "." + countH2 + "." + countH3 + "." + ++countH4;
            } else if (_tagName === "H5") {
                countH6 = 0; /* Reset next level number */
                return countH1 + "." + countH2 + "." + countH3 + "." + countH4 + "." + ++countH5;
            } else if (_tagName === "H6") {
                return countH1 + "." + countH2 + "." + countH3 + "." + countH4 + "." + countH5 + "." + ++countH6;
            }
        }
    }
    /* Register TOC function after SP page is loaded */
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("buildToc");
</script>
```

Source: https://blog.lsonline.fr/2018/12/23/create-a-dynamic-table-of-content-for-your-sharepoint-wiki-pages/

Comment: Start your loop at 1 instead of 0?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: _"I have no clue. Please do this for me."_ is not the scope of SO

Comment: Don't iterate live HTMLCollection, use static NodeList (returned by `document.querySelectorAll`) or an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the meantime i got a hint from the code writer and the code below matches exactly my needs.

```
<!-- 
The TOC Container.
The most important thing to note is the ID.
The ID is used by the CSS and the JavaScript code.
-->
<ul id="sp-toc"></ul>

<style type="text/css">
    #sp-toc {
        padding: 10px;
        /* Add a padding between the border and the TOC content */
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        /* Add a background color of the TOC */
        min-width: 200px;
        /* Add only a minimal width like that, the TOC can be extensible */
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        /* Add a border arround the TOC */
        list-style: none;
        /* Remove default style list */
    }

    #sp-toc li {
        /* If you need to add custom style on all <li> */
    }

    #sp-toc li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        /* Remove default link underline */
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h1 {
        /* currently, the first level supported by the script */
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h2 {
        /* Add a indentation greatter than the previous one */
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h3 {
        /* Add a indentation greatter than the previous one */
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h4 {
        /* Add a indentation greatter than the previous one */
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h5 {
        /* Add a indentation greatter than the previous one */
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    #sp-toc .class-toc-h6 {
        /* Add a indentation greatter than the previous one */
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * The main function to build TOC
     */
    function buildToc() {
        /* Init title level counters */
        var countH1 = countH2 = countH3 = countH4 = countH5 = countH6 = 0;

        /**
         * DOMElement : the TOC container retrieved by ID
         */
        var toc = document.getElementById("sp-toc");

        /**
         * Insert into TOC container the chapters
         */
        toc.innerHTML = nodesToc();

        /**
         * TOC Builder
         */
        function nodesToc() {
            /* Get all HTML tags from the current page */
            var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            var tagList = "H1;H2;H3;H4;H5;H6;";
            var str = "";
            var pageTitle = false;
            /* Loop on each HTML tag */
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                /* If tag is a title tag */
                if (tagList.indexOf(obj[i].tagName + ";") >= 0) {
                    if ('H1' == obj[i].tagName && !pageTitle) {
                        pageTitle = true;
                    } else {
                        /* Get the number of the multilevel list in accordance with the current title */
                        var lvl = getNumberLevel(obj[i].tagName);
                        /* HTML template */
                        str += "<li class='" + getClassLvl(obj[i].tagName) + "'><a href='#title-" + i + "'>" + lvl + " " + obj[i].innerHTML + "</a></li>";
                        obj[i].id = "title-" + i;
                    }
                }
            }
            return str;
        }

        /**
         * Get CSS class in accordance with the title level
         */
        function getClassLvl(_tagName) {
            return "class-toc-h" + _tagName.replace(/h/ig, '');
        }

        /**
         * Multilevel list generator
         */
        function getNumberLevel(_tagName) {
            if (_tagName === "H1") {
                countH2 = countH3 = countH4 = countH5 = countH6 = 0;
                return ++countH1;
            } else if (_tagName === "H2") {
                countH3 = countH4 = countH5 = countH6 = 0;
                return countH1 + "." + ++countH2;
            } else if (_tagName === "H3") {
                countH4 = countH5 = countH6 = 0; /* Reset next level number */
                return countH1 + "." + countH2 + "." + ++countH3;
            } else if (_tagName === "H4") {
                countH5 = countH6 = 0; /* Reset next level number */
                return countH1 + "." + countH2 + "." + countH3 + "." + ++countH4;
            } else if (_tagName === "H5") {
                countH6 = 0; /* Reset next level number */
                return countH1 + "." + countH2 + "." + countH3 + "." + countH4 + "." + ++countH5;
            } else if (_tagName === "H6") {
                return countH1 + "." + countH2 + "." + countH3 + "." + countH4 + "." + countH5 + "." + ++countH6;
            }
        }
    }
    /* Register TOC function after SP page is loaded */
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("buildToc");
</script>
```

Source: https://gitlab.lsonline.fr/SharePoint/javascript-customactions/-/snippets/83

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your for loop that begins with

`for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {`

You can put on the first line of the loop (before If tag is a title tag)

`if (i === 0) continue;`

Comment: thx for your answer! I tried your version but it results in an empty ToC-Div, sry. Similar to my answer @atmos_msft, i currently dont have enough time to look for furthers details. I will do that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can judge the attribute values of all the elements you get. If the element is h1 and the id attribute value is "pageTitle", skip it.

[image]

Comment: thx for your answer, but currently i dont have enough time to learn how i can use this, but for sure, i will do it.